# How do I restrict S3 + Cloudfront staging server to specific IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to setup my staging server to be served via S3 and cloudfront. Here is my bucket policy below.

a) If I access the S3 url directly, everything works fine.

b) If I access the cloudfront root domain, www.staging.example.com, everything works fine.

However, once I go to www.staging.example.com/login (or any non-root url), I get a `403 Forbidden AccessDenied` error. How do I fix this?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::staging-server/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "XXX",
                        "XXX",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to serve the site via CloudFront only, then you should reconfigure the S3 bucket policy to allow access to the CloudFront Origin Access Identity of your CloudFront distribution, and remove all IP address conditions from the bucket policy.

To restrict access to the distribution to an IP whitelist, configure [AWS WAF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) and an [IPSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_IPSet.html). Use WAF v2, not the original WAF.

On the non-root url question, do you actually have a document named `login`?

Comment: Yes I do have a document named login. However, I think it was a caching issue, because I deleted and remade the distribution and now I get AccessDenied on every page.

Comment: Got it. You can also invalidate the distribution to save time.